# Link functionality in Google Chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension

How do you enable hyperlinks to be clickable within a chrome extension?  Do you have to create an event as described [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/events.html)?  I'm outputting a list of urls within a popout page, and while the html output is correct, nothing happens when I click them.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, you do because a popup is like a page I guess so you have to use createTab in an onclick event.
Change your output to something like this....

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="chrome.tabs.create({url:this.href})">Bunyips!</a>
```

...dont forget to add tabs to your permissions in the manifest.
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html

Answer (score -2):

It looks like a straight forward thing. you just use `<a href="your_page.html">link</a>` to insert a link into page. 
you might want to paste the source code maybe there is something that would help.

Comment: I'm displaying my page as a popup via a browser action in manifest.json.  Here's the code:  

"browser_action": {
    "popup": "feed.html"
  },   

I'm creating normal links within the file, but it doesn't seem to know where to open because the content exists within the popup.

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to bypass the popup limitations by adding target="_blank" to my links, forcing them to open in a new tab.